# Одновременно не выводятся оба QLineSeries

Tags: c++, qt

В данном фрагменте кода я пытаюсь вывести некий график с двумя Series. Для более быстрого вывода я удаляю, заполняю Series и затем добавляю их обратно. Проблема в том что при одновременном удалении и добавлении Series 2 не выводится.

- Series 1 --- это обычная рандомная функция.
- Series 2 --- уровень 0, для теста на данный момент 400.

В данном случае будет выведен только Series1:

```
void MainWindow::_drawGraphic(QVector<double> dataArray, const double 
                  &minValueOfDataArray, const double &maxValueOfDataArray)
{
//Вывод графика
    Series1->clear();
    Series2->clear();

    Chart1->removeSeries(Series1);
    Chart1->removeSeries(Series2);

    for(int i=0; i<dataArray.size()-1; i++)
    {
        Series1->append(i, dataArray[i]);
        Series2->append(i, 400);
    }

    axisX->setRange(firstCount, secondCount);
    axisY->setRange(minValueOfDataArray, maxValueOfDataArray);
    axisZero->setRange(minValueOfDataArray, maxValueOfDataArray);
    Chart1->addSeries(Series1);
    Chart1->addSeries(Series2);
}
```

**[Неправильная работа]:**

[image]

Если я буду удалять только Series1, то все будет работать верно и Series2 тоже появится, но вывод будет очень замедлен, а при больших данных программа вовсе упадет:

```
//Вывод графика
    Series1->clear();
    Series2->clear();

    Chart1->removeSeries(Series1);
    //Chart1->removeSeries(Series2);

    for(int i=0; i<dataArray.size()-1; i++)
    {
        Series1->append(i, dataArray[i]);
        Series2->append(i, 400);
    }

    axisX->setRange(firstCount, secondCount);
    axisY->setRange(minValueOfDataArray, maxValueOfDataArray);
    axisZero->setRange(minValueOfDataArray, maxValueOfDataArray);
    Chart1->addSeries(Series1);
    //Chart1->addSeries(Series2);
```

**[Правильная работа 'Зеленая линия Series2']:**

[image]

Есть какие-либо предложения или решения? Заранее спасибо.

> ***В общем помощи нигде не нашел, пришлось ставить qCustomPlot, такой проблемы там не было выявлено***

Comment: может их надо сначала удалить, а только потом очистить?

Comment: @VTT ничего не изменилось... Series2 также не выводится